# Regex within a for each loop in pig

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I am currently using a UDF to get an output, however a regular expression will do the same and probably quicker!

I am having a problem running the code in pig, this is the line of code I am trying to run.

```
data = FOREACH f GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX EXTRACT(col4,'(?:\.)([^\.]*\.?[^\.]*)$')) AS (url:chararray) ;
```

This line of code comes up with an error Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('

The regex works by getting google.co.uk and will return .co.uk, google.com will return .com
Link here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?372tm

My idea is then to count by the number of tlds. e.g 3 co.uk

```
 countURL = group data by url;
 result = foreach countURL generate group, COUNT($1);
```

If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- You are missing the `_` in `regex_extract`
- You need to specify the group `0`
- The dots needs to be double quoted `\\`

`data = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(url,'(?:\\.)([^\\.]*\\.?[^\\.]*)$', 0));`

This gives `.com` for `google.com`